# Usando mysql_num_rows com PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mysql-num-rows

Alterei o método de conexão da minha página ao meu Banco de Dados via PDO. Eu utilizava até então um código de paginação só que agora está retornando o erro:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\n_archaeus\inc\index.php on line 85

Meu código está assim:

```
$pg = isset($_GET['pg'])?$_GET['pg']:"1";

$quantidade = 3;

$ini = ($pg*$quantidade) - $quantidade;

$qry = "
SELECT 
content.id_content, 
content.img, 
content.titulo, 
povos.pv, 
cat.categoria, 
content.inicio, 
content.fim, 
content.content, 
regiao.reg, 
regiao.wmap
FROM cat 
INNER JOIN regiao 
INNER JOIN povos 
INNER JOIN content ON povos.id_povos = content.civ 
AND regiao.id_regiao = povos.regiao 
AND cat.id_cat = content.clas
ORDER BY inicio 
LIMIT $ini, $quantidade";

    $resultado = $PDO->query( $qry );
    $rows = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows as $key => $linha) {

        $civ = $linha['pv'];
        $clas = $linha['categoria'];
        $inicio = $linha['inicio'];
        $fim = $linha['fim'];
        $titulo = $linha['titulo'];
        $conteudo = $linha['content'];
        $imagem = $linha['img'];
        $reg = $linha['reg'];
        $wmap = $linha['wmap'];

        echo  $civ; etc. etc. etc...

       }

$sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY inicio ";
    $res_2 = $PDO->query( $sql_2 );
    $row_2 = $res_2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_2);

$paginas = ceil($total_registros/$quantidade);
$links = '9';

echo "<br><center><p class='paginas'><a href='?id=37&pg=1'>Primeira P&aacute;gina </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

for($i = $pg-$links; $i <= $pg-1; $i++){
        if($i<=0){
            }else{
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?id=37&pg=".$i."'><strong>".$i."</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
    }

    echo "<a href=#> [ $pg ] </a>";

for($i = $pg+1; $i <= $pg+$links; $i++){
        if($i>$paginas){
            }else{
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?id=37&pg=".$i."'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
    }

echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?id=37&pg=".$paginas."'>&Uacute;ltima P&aacute;gina </a></p></center>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
?>
```

Comment: Acho que em `mysql_num_rows($sql_2)` deveria ser `mysql_num_rows($res_2)`, certo? Caso contrário, você deve utilizar `$res_2->rowCount()` que é o mais aconselhado quando se usa uma conexão PDO. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Olá Caio. Obrigado pela resposta, porém ainda não consegui fazer funcionar essa consulta. Meu código ficou assim    $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY inicio ";
 $res_2 = $PDO->query( $sql_2 );
 $row_2 = $res_2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total_registros -> row_count($res_2);

$paginas = ceil($total_registros/$quantidade);
   e a mensagem de erro ficou assim: "Notice: Undefined variable: total_registros in D:\xampp\htdocs\n_archaeus\inc\index.php on line 86

Fatal error: Call to a member function row_count() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\n_archaeus\inc\index.php on line

Comment: Você precisa chamar `rowCount()` do `Statement` que é a usa variável `$res_2`. Neste caso você deve chamar `$total_registros = $res_2->rowCount()` para ter o total de registros selecionados.

Comment: Obrigado Caio, agora deu certo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foi preciso chamar `rowCount()` do Statement que é a usa variável `$res_2`. Neste caso foi chamado

```
$total_registros = $res_2->rowCount()
```

Para ter o total de registros selecionados.